# Is it possible to send userfriendlyexception from controller with sweet alert

Tags: sweetalert, aspnetboilerplate

I want to return sweet alerts from controller to warn a user about customized errors according to my needs. I could not figure it out in controller. Basically I throw userfriendlyexception from my action but errors are shown in another way.  I have referenced abp.UI in the controllers. I have changed the layout's html and css, but still including sweet alert's js and css files and it's working in the service level as a proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should directly work. What is your Abp version? Which framework (AspNet Core or AspNet MVC) and UI (Angular or ASP.NET MVC) you are using? Have you created your project from https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates? If so when and what type of template?

Comment: abp version is 2.0.1.. it's almost the latest one. error.cshtml in the mvc shared folder is being sent to the end-user whenever my custom userfriendlyexception occurs.  example basic exception throwing, it returns error.cshtml not sweet alert. abp.ui already referenced by the way.                                                                 
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new UserFriendlyException(L("NotFound"), L("UserNotFound"));
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Boilerplate has different behaviours based on return type of your Controller's Action:

- If action returns `JsonResult` or another object (or their async `Task<T>` versions) then it returns an `AjaxResponse` and client side can handle it and show a sweetalert message. So, if you call an action with AJAX and not returning HTML then explicitly use `JsonResult` of other POCO object as return value of your action.
- If action's return type is `ActionResult`, `ViewResult` or `PartialViewResult` (or their async `Task<T>` versions) then it returns the Error view.

See documentation for more: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#exception-filter

Comment: thank you for the response. I will read it along from scratch and let you know.